# Gettin an erron in Atom but not if I copy paste it in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor

I'm trying to learn Python. I am currently using Jupyter Notebook and Atom as a text editor.

This is my code:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(len(grid[i])):
    for l in range(0, len(grid)):
        if l < len(grid)-1:
            print(grid[l][i], end='')
        else:
            print(grid[l][i])
```

When I use run File_name in Jupyter I get

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

But if I copy paste it in Jupyter it works just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks as if ``for i in range(len(grid[i])):`` and ``for l in range(0, len(grid)):`` are in the wrong order. Also: consider to iterate the list items directly instead of using an index variable (e.g. ``for sublist in grid:``)

Comment: "it in Jupyter it works just fine" most probably you have `i` defined in another cell (or it was defined previously in the session). Try again with a fresh notebook. You should get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It code works in Jupyter because the `i` is defined in other cells in the same Jupiter notebook.

I guess this is what you want to do:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for row in range(len(grid)):
    for col in range(len(grid[0])):
        print(grid[row][col], end='')
    print()



>>>
......
.OO...
OOOO..
OOOOO.
.OOOOO
OOOOO.
OOOO..
.OO...
......
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work for me neither in IDE nor in Jupyter.

It does complain about 'i' as it does not know what 'i' is in the first line of your nested for loops.

```
for i in range(len(grid[i])):
    for l in range(0, len(grid)):
        if l < len(grid)-1:
            print(grid[l][i], end='')
        else:
            print(grid[l][i])
```

the first line is:

```
  for i in range(len(grid[i])):
```

so for 'i' in range ...  this would be fine if it would know what range is ...

so let's look into range and how you defined it:

```
range(len(grid[i]))
```

so, i can see you expect to return a range of (len...)

so e.g. range(x)

your x = len(grid[i])

what is the len ... len of what?

let's look into len ...

```
grid[i]
```

what is grid of what?

grid of i

so... what is i?

of course it is not the i from top level of your for ... loop if you follow this logic you notice Python compilers similarly to human can not understand what is i ...

define i first ... e.g. i = 5 and then your code would work.

Comment: I do understand your point, but then:
- how do I tell it to run for each value of different lines with possible different lenghts?
- why it does work in Jupyter if I copy paste it?